# mysqld not starting up

Tags: mysql, installation, mysqld

I installed mysql on ubuntu. mysqld does not startup with the following errors -

```
2017-04-16T00:22:35.320639Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2017-04-16T00:22:35.321014Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 170415 19:22:35
2017-04-16T00:22:35.321036Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2017-04-16T00:22:35.321354Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2017-04-16T00:22:35.322301Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2017-04-16T00:22:35.322490Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2017-04-16T00:22:35.323247Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2017-04-16T00:22:35.323361Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2017-04-16T00:22:35.323379Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2017-04-16T00:22:35.323411Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-04-16T00:22:35.323450Z 0 [ERROR] Could not create unix socket lock file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock.lock.
2017-04-16T00:22:35.323464Z 0 [ERROR] Unable to setup unix socket lock file.
2017-04-16T00:22:35.323476Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2017-04-16T00:22:35.323497Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2017-04-16T00:22:35.323545Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Did you upgrade recently?  If so, did you run `mysql_upgrade`?

Comment: What does your `my.cnf` file look like?

Answer (score 0):

It does not solve the problem as such but you should be able to bypass it by adding the skip-external-locking to my.cnf under [mysqld]

Should at least get the server starting while you find out the root of the problem.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/external-locking.html